# Is it possible to have Firebase authentication via Facebook in a Phonegap App?

Tags: cordova, firebase

I have made my first Firebase based webpage with Facebook authentication and it works really well (and easy to setup).

But I guess it is not easy to embed the html on a Phonegap App that would run on iOs/Android.  I assume that the Facebook (or Twitter) authentication would not work directly on the App WebView.

Is it possible to make it work?  Any hints?

Comment: What problems are you running into, specifically?

Comment: PhoneGap is not officially supported for these authentication flows (yet), but we're looking into this issue. Feel free to follow-up with me directly for status updates (rob at firebase.com), and I will post again here once we have made progress on this issue.

Comment: Andrew: the web authentication flow assumes that the user submits his cerdentials (email/password) on a popup window, which returns the control to the original url after authentication. With Phonegap (or similar approaches to embed html pages in a native App) the html runs in a WebView (with no explicit url public to the Internet).  So I assume that the current authentication flow will fail launching the pop-up window and giving control back to the original page.

Comment: Rob:  Thanks for the answer!  I will be waiting for updates on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase support for PhoneGap was announced today: http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/04/16/firebase-phonegap-integration/